# Can't install aptitude on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, repository

Where I try to install aptitude, i get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: aptitude-common (= 0.7.4-2ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libcwidget3v5 but it is not going to be installed
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed
 virtualbox-5.0 : Depends: libqt4-opengl (>= 4:4.7.2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: dkms but it is not going to be installed
 vivaldi-stable : Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: pepperflashplugin-nonfree but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get -f install` as suggested in the last line of the error?

Answer (score 0):

apt-get -f install
solved it, should have read it properly.